# Getting Category Path in URL for EE 1.13

Tags: url, ee-1.13

In Magento Enterprise Edition 1.11 we have the URLs did the following

```
Category Lv 1 - http://me.dev.local/men-s
Category Lv 2 - http://me.dev.local/men-s/clothing
Category Lv 3 - http://me.dev.local/men-s/clothing/activewear
Product       - http://me.dev.local/men-s/clothing/activewear/shirt-001
```

since upgrading to 1.13, the URLs no longer do this, instead it's only really the last element that is in the url (ie. men-s, activewear, shirt-001)

now i found an option in System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations called "Use Categories Path for Product URLs", setting this to Yes allowed the products to work like they did before in 1.11

with some of the categories we have, using the same example as above we have a Men's and Women's Level 1 Categories, both would have Clothing, both would have Activewear, because of the upgrade to 1.13, one fo the 2 categories is now has a -# at the end (in most cases it's -1 but we also have kids categories so some get a -2 or -3)

i am wondering if there is a setting to get Categories to have the URL Path like what i have listed above to appear like that in 1.13

Comment: This problem could be related with Magento EE 1.13 version rollback, which had a bug related exactly with catalog URLs. Please check the Magento EE Download section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.13 there is no `url_path` notion any more for products and categories. There are only `url_key` attributes. And those MUST be unique. Which is why they have been changed for you by upgrade scripts. Unless you decide to develop a workaround the other solution is to redirect your old urls to new ones.

Answer (score -1):

In 1.13 there is an option to use categories path for product urls but there is no option to remove categories paths from category urls

So, i've created a simple module to workaround this.

https://github.com/alitopaloglu/ExcParentCatPathFromSubCatUrls

ATTENTION - DEVELOPED FOR ONLY MAGENTO ENTERPRISE EDITION v1.13

This module adds a yes/no option labelled as "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs" on

Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options

to remove parent category path from url and change it from www.domain.com/cat1/cat2 to www.domain.com/cat2

USAGE :

1. Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options
2. Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"
3. Refresh category url index

Option YES => www.domain.com/cat1/cat2

Option NO => www.domain.com/cat2

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a little more technical explanation as well?